# Online/Offline status in aws chime sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-chime-sdk

A user's online/offline presence can be determined in AWS Chime webapp,but there is no User Presence indicator feature in aws chime SDK.Why?And how to implement it in AWS Chime SDK.

Comment: Is this the `EndpointState` on the [AppInstanceUserEndpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chime/latest/APIReference/API_identity-chime_AppInstanceUserEndpoint.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi, Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: The AWS Chime SDK focuses primarily on providing real-time communication capabilities like video calling, audio calling, and messaging. It's designed to be a flexible and scalable toolkit for developers to build communication features into their applications. The Online/Offline status should be custom implemented, for example using dynamodb.